# Ruby delete specific value from hash and replace with another value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

Is there a clear way to loop through the hash below and replace the specific value(s) with the value(s) in the 'Fills' array?

```
codes = ['AA', 'BB']
fills = ['FOUR', 'FIVE']
```

This empty hash gets populated by an 'each do' statement where is picks out the info from 'main_hash' based on the keys in the 'codes' array.

```
hash = {}

main_hash = {'AA' => ['1', 'TEXT', 'ONE'],
             'BB' => ['2', 'TEXT', 'TWO'],
             'CC' => ['3', 'TEXT', 'THREE']}
```

Ouput:
I want to replace the specific value in the new 'hash' so the output looks like below:

```
hash = {'AA' => ['1', 'TEXT', 'FOUR'],
        'BB' => ['2', 'TEXT', 'FIVE']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```rb
# Input
fills = ['FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX']

hash = {
  'AA' => ['1', 'ONE'],
  'BB' => ['2', 'TWO'],
  'CC' => ['3', 'THREE']
}
```

```rb
hash.transform_values { |i, _| [i, fills[i.to_i - 1]] }
```

```rb
# output

{
  'AA' => ['1', 'FOUR'],
  'BB' => ['2', 'FIVE'],
  'CC' => ['3', 'SIX']
}
```

**Update**:

As your incoming data is changed the solution will be:

```rb
h = {"AA"=>["1", "FOUR"], "BB"=>["2", "FIVE"]}

h.transform_values { |x| x.insert(1, 'TEXT') }
```

```rb
# Output

{
  'AA' => ['1', 'TEXT', 'FOUR'], 
  'BB' => ['2', 'TEXT', 'FIVE']
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did manage to get it working but made a slight change. If you look at the code now whenever I try your solution I get the following: {"AA"=>["1", "FOUR"], "BB"=>["2", "FIVE"]}. 
I want to display hash = {'AA' => ['1', 'TEXT', 'FOUR'], 'BB' => ['2', 'TEXT', 'FIVE']} as the output. Thanks.

Comment: You provided totally new values

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have made it clear the first time.

Comment: You need to update you question not completely change it. I updated my answer